# Trying to call a method from 1st class activity and keep the same argument in a 2nd class activity (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Currently finishing up an app I have been working on but I'm kinda stuck on this last thing.

The app has 2 activities, one with buttons that are categories and the other shows the information according to the button pressed. For example if you click the button Fast food, it goes to the 2nd screen and displays info on that.

I'm trying to get a refresh button on the 2nd activity that will call a method in the 1st activity to refresh new information depending on the button pressed. The problem is that I don't know how to make it so the method keeps the same argument when called. What I mean is, if fast food was clicked, the refresh button would get new info that still relates to the fast food category.

Here's the relevant code in the Main activity:

```
public void yelpSearch(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button: buttoncategory = "Restaurant";
        break;
        case R.id.button2: buttoncategory = "Chinese restaurant";
        break;
        case R.id.button3: buttoncategory = "Fast Food";
        break;
```

and this on the 2nd Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
        Refresh();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void Refresh() {
MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
mActivity.yelpSearch();
}
```

I'm not sure what to put inside mActivity.yelpSearch(); 
I tried using (View view) but it'll say cannot resolve symbol view. And if I make a local variable for view, it'll say not initialized and I don't know what to set it as

Any help would be awesome, been googling on this for a while now and searched through tons of questions on here as well. I'm still new at this so bear with me

Comment: You should never create a new `Activity` with `new`, it's just wrong.

Comment: Read up on [Intent](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html).

Comment: What about passing the previous activity's reference and call the function accordingly?

Comment: @DanielNugent Yeah I knew that was probably not the right way of doing it, but that's why I'm asking here cuz I'm quite lost on how to do it.

Comment: Reading up on intent. And @Mr.777, could you elaborate on that a little.

Comment: Read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424667/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-another-activity-on-click-of-a-widget-button/26425484#26425484

Comment: @DanielNugent ok what I got from that is I should make this method a separate class. Now my question is, will I have to use intent to get the button IDs since they are from the activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass data between activities?

First Activity(Send DATA):

```
String data="YourXXXdata" 
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("DATANAME", data);
startActivity(intent)
```

second Activity(Receive DATA):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("DATANAME");
}
```

The data now is in `String value`

*you have to put in data the value you need depend you preview select button.

Comment: Where would be a good place to put this? Also for String data, would I be storing the button name there?

Comment: Ok, so I tried this and the thing is I'm trying to pass an object of type View into yelpSearch(). Apparently Intent is only for primitive types. I found that I could probably do this with Serializable or Parcelable but I'm still trying to figure out how to use that in my own code

Answer (score -2):

Make your `yelpSearch` method `static`
and call it like this from 2nd activity `MainActivity.yelpSearch();`

Comment: This is very bad advise.

Comment: Read this answer, it should explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424667/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-another-activity-on-click-of-a-widget-button/26425484#26425484